# QGIS compilation using Ninja

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux

I am compiling QGIS in Ubuntu 20 with Ninja. Compilation build succesful. Now I have made some changes in UI file and .cpp file and want to recompile again like we do in Visual Studio.

How to do this?